# How can some services read what you type into the dialpad while you're on a phone call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iphone, phone-call

Today I was calling USPS and got redirected to their over the phone bot. I was wondering what they use that can detect what you type into the dialpad, for example "press 1 for main menu". I was also wondering if I could replicate the same thing in python.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by "over-the-phone but" you mean it's a bot that you can interact with during an actual phone call; they use [DTMF tones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling) to detect the numbers you press, by listening to the actual tones in the phone call. In the past, you could usually hear the actual tones when pressing the numbers, such as when on a landline, but nowadays, phones tend to play a generic sound and mute the DTMF tones when you dial them.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably lots of ways.  Here's one I have heard of:
You can use Twilio along with python to create a phone bot.  The Twilio API should provide you with most things that you need for the phone.  The rest will probably be much the same, for example,

```
if phoneinput == button-1:
    ...
```

Here is a quick tutorial I found online for reference: https://www.fullstackpython.com/blog/make-phone-calls-python.html

Comment: @Random Davis (other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68072512/14428026) I actually didn't know that.  That's pretty cool.  I always thought they used some kind of input to detect what you pressed or such, but the tones were always there and I never thought about them...